# What are the different item quality characters?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

What do the item quality character designations mean? What quality is `*<*sword*>*`, etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A full list and description is available at [the df wiki](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Quality).

In order from worst to best, with their additions to item quality:

- Nothing = 1x
- - = 2x
- + = 3x
- * = 4x
- ≡ = 5x
- ☼ = 12x
- Artifact items, (ones with a unique name) = 10x in the latest version, 120x in 0.28

The [page for the previous version](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/40d:Item_quality) is far more detailed, but some information may be out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Item Name —      Standart — 1x
-Item Name- — Well-crafted  — 2x
+Item Name+ — Finely-crafted    — 3x
* Item Name *   — Superior quality  — 4x
≡Item Name≡ — Exceptional   — 5x
☼Item Name☼ — Masterful — 12x
Unique name — Artifact  — 12x
«Item Name» — Decorated object  — Varies

Decorations have quality levels, too. An item of any quality (except artifacts) can have a decoration of any quality. (There are no artifact quality decorations.) The quality level of a decoration is shown by the same signs (-, +, *, ≡, ☼) just outside the double angle-brackets («,»). Thus, a *«+steel battle axe+»* is a finely-crafted steel battle axe with superior decorations on it, and a «☼steel battle axe☼» is a masterfully crafted steel battle axe with decorations of standard quality.

Source: dwarffortresswiki

Comment: If you check the description of an artifact, it always has a number of artifact-quality decorations on it.  It's true that you can't add more later, though (or add artifact-quality decorations to anything else).